# Getting different result when printing expression written in reverse order

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Why I'm getting different result on the 3rd line?
The output is:

```
1
1
0
1
```

Shouldn't I receive at the line no. 3 also the output `1` instead of `0`? It has the same syntax as the other lines.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = -3;
    bool a = (x % 2 == 1) || (x < 0);
    bool b = (x < 0) || (x % 2 == 1);
    cout << a << "\n";                              // line 1
    cout << b << "\n";                              // line 2
    cout << (x % 2 == 1) || (x < 0); cout << "\n";  // line 3
    cout << (x < 0) || (x % 2 == 1); cout << "\n";  // line 4
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), which `operator<<` has higher than `operator||`, only the

```
(x % 2 == 1)
```

part is printed. The rest is like doing `cout || (x < 0);`. (note that `std::cout`, like any other `std::basic_ios` derived stream is implicitly convertible to `bool`)

With parentheses, it looks like this:

```
(cout << (x % 2 == 1)) || (x < 0);
```

Line 4 printed `1`, because `(x < 0)` was true and you switched the operands - this should be clear now.

**Solution:** parenthesize the `operator||` call:

```
cout << (x % 2 == 1 || x < 0);
```

<sup>Parentheses around `operator||`'s operands are, on the other hand, redundant.</sup>